# Joomla/k2 category article count to only include published articles

Tags: database, joomla, k2

Im using Joomla/k2.
I have the following code which displays the number of k2 items/articles within a category.

```
<?php 
$cat_id = $this->item->category->id;
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$select = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #__k2_items WHERE catid = $cat_id";
$db->setQuery($select);
$noitems = $db->loadresult();
echo $noitems; 
?>
```

Id like to modify this to only count 'Published' k2 items/articles (not include unpublished k2 items/articles).

Any help would be very much appreciated!
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To get only the published items you can do this

```
<?php 
$cat_id = $this->item->category->id;
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$select = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #__k2_items WHERE catid = $cat_id AND published = 1";
$db->setQuery($select);
$noitems = $db->loadresult();
echo $noitems; 
?>
```